# case_when works in one instance, not another

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to summarise data by quarter. However, the quarters do not follow normal quarters. My quarter starts December.

I can breakdown data into quarters using following code:

```
require(tidyverse)

# generate dummy data
data <- data.frame(value = runif(12, min = 10000, max = 12000),
                   month = 1:12,
                   stringsAsFactors = F)

qtr <- data %>% 
  mutate(quarter = case_when(month == 1:3 ~ 1,
                             month == 4:6 ~ 2,
                             month == 7:9 ~ 3,
                             month == 9:12 ~ 4))
```

Results as expected:

```
       value month quarter
1  11959.56     1       1
2  10389.29     2       1
3  10731.31     3       1
4  10433.61     4       2
5  11969.98     5       2
6  10240.25     6       2
7  11415.40     7       3
8  10942.18     8       3
9  11114.58     9       3
10 11109.37    10       4
11 11448.45    11       4
12 10940.48    12       4
```

Now I try and change the quarterly breakdown so quarters start in December e.g.

```
qtr <- data %>% 
      mutate(quarter = case_when(month == 1:2 ~ 1,
                             month == 3:5 ~ 2,
                             month == 6:8 ~ 3,
                             month == 9:11 ~ 4,
                             month == 12 ~ 1))
```

And I get:

```
      value month quarter
1  11959.56     1       1
2  10389.29     2       1
3  10731.31     3      NA
4  10433.61     4      NA
5  11969.98     5      NA
6  10240.25     6      NA
7  11415.40     7      NA
8  10942.18     8      NA
9  11114.58     9      NA
10 11109.37    10      NA
11 11448.45    11      NA
12 10940.48    12       1
```

Why do I get NA's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer :**

Use `%in%` instead of `==` since you want to compare multiple values

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
   mutate(quarter = case_when(month %in% c(1:2, 12) ~ 1,
                              month %in% 3:5 ~ 2,
                              month %in% 6:8 ~ 3,
                              month %in% 9:11 ~ 4))

#      value month quarter
#1  11216.52     1       1
#2  10767.37     2       1
#3  10631.57     3       2
#4  11906.64     4       2
#5  11575.19     5       2
#6  11403.56     6       3
#7  10315.16     7       3
#8  11631.13     8       3
#9  11083.61     9       4
#10 11755.59    10       4
#11 10247.68    11       4
#12 10485.54    12       1
```

---

**Long Answer**

The first option "works" by chance because of the numbers chosen and the recycling property in R.

For example, consider this case

```
1:10 == 4:6
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

> Warning message:
>   In 1:10 == 4:6 :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

What actually happens here is `4:6` is recycled and it becomes

```
a1 <- rep(4:6, length.out = 10)
a1
#[1] 4 5 6 4 5 6 4 5 6 4
```

and now this is compared with

```
a2 <- 1:10
a2
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

element by element. Check values at position `4:6` in `a1` and `a2`

```
a1[4:6]
#[1] 4 5 6
a2[4:6]
#[1] 4 5 6
```

they both are the same and hence, you receive `TRUE` values at those positions when you compare them in `case_when`. Same happens for rest of the cases in your first attempt and you think that it is working.

It would not work as expected even if you change one number here or there. For example,

```
data %>% 
  mutate(quarter = case_when(month == 1:2 ~ 1,
                             month == 3:6 ~ 2,
                             month == 7:9 ~ 3,
                             month == 9:12 ~ 4))

#      value month quarter
#1  11436.83     1       1
#2  10524.27     2       1
#3  10110.57     3      NA
#4  11755.68     4      NA
#5  10757.70     5      NA
#6  10203.56     6      NA
#7  11346.90     7       3
#8  10308.79     8       3
#9  10328.54     9       3
#10 10732.88    10       4
#11 11150.69    11       4
#12 10990.28    12       4
```

For your second case, `3:5` is recycled and compared element wise

```
a3 <- rep(3:5, length.out = 10)

a2 == a3
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Since there was no match all the values are `FALSE` and you get `NA`s in `case_when`

Comment: The last case `month %in% 12` can be combined with the first case.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the long explanation!